# Coordinates validation in java

Tags: java, arrays, arguments, coordinates, command-line-arguments

Suppose that I am passing integer coordinates as arguments in java.For example, (1,2), (1,1), (2,2) would be passed as 1 2 1 1 2 2. Suppose further that I give each coordinate pair a label say 1,,,n where n is the number of pairs of coordinates. I would like to find a way so that if the same coordinate pair is given more than once, the label is updated to the new value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class  with x ,y coordinates and label as its properties , store each object of this  class in a hashmap use  coordinate pair as its key and label as value , this will serve your purpose